# Accidently deleted SVN tag

Tags: svn, tags

I accidentally deleted a SVN tag. Is it possible to recreate this tag easily ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tag is just a copy of the SVN tree at a certain point. You should be able to recreate it in the same way that you created it. eg `svn cp trunk tags/my_tag`
If you need it to be a tag of a particular revision, then you pass in the revision number with `-r`

Alternatively, you can probably restore the original tag by doing a "reverse merge" on the checkin where you deleted the tag - but that's more complicated. Google for that if you'd like to try it instead.

Comment: Recreating the tag by using `svn cp -r` is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Oh great, didn't know the parameter -r ... saves a lot of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the command line, the typical method is to do a "reverse merge". For example, if version 125 was the checkin that deleted the tag directory, then you would execute a command like this: `svn merge -r 125:124`. Subversion will pull the previous version with the tag out of the history into your working copy.  Once there, you can do a commit to commit the change back in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't undo. You can re-create the same tag copying the same revision from the trunk and giving it the same name.